# SharePoint 2013 managed metadata navigation and custom sort order

Tags: 2013, navigation, managed-metadata

I'm trying out the managed navigation in SP 2013 and cannot set the custom sort order. I select "Use custom sort order" and save it but when I reload the page "Use default sort order according to current language" is selected again.

Is this a bug or what am I doing wrong?

I use a test environment with SP 2013 RTM in Cloudshare

Comment: Is this still an issue or was it resolved?

Comment: I think it's an issue in SP 2013 RTM. It works in my current production environment.

Comment: Can you post that as an answer and mark it as your answer?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.  You must first turn on Custom Sort from the web application's top level site collection's Term Store Management Tool.  Then it is available for use in subsequent site collections and web sites. At least that's what toggled it on for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with default **Department** term set in **People** group. I was unable to update it because the term set **Owner** was not set. And since this field is on the different tab I didn't see the validation message.